# Function Problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**If $f(x)$ is a function satisfying $ \displaystyle f(x+y) = f(x) \cdot f(y)  \text { for all } x,y \in \mathbb{N} \text{ such that } f(1) = 3 \text { and } $ $ \sum_{x=1}^{n} f(x) = 120 $, then find the value of $n$.**

How to approach this one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: Knowing the value of $f(1)$, you can get the value of $f(2)=f(1+1)$ from the defining equation. Knowing these two, you can get value of $f(3)=f(1+2)$ and so on.

Comment: +1,thanks.Using your hint, $f(x) = \left[f(1)\right]^x = 3^x$; Then in the summation which is in geometric progression, $3^n = 3^4$;which gives $n = 4$.

Comment: @Debanjan: Indeed.